# How to use two different RTC modules (ds1307/ds3231) on the same PI

Tags: rtc, ds1307

The question is: How to use the same SD image when you don't know which RTC module will be connected on top of Raspberry PI?

I have two modules in use in config.txt:

```
dtparam=i2c_vc=on
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
```

and

```
dtparam=i2c_vc=on
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307
```

I have tried specifying both(with dtoverlay=merged) but an error happens and /dev/rtc0 didn't appear.
One by one they worked like a charm, but I don't want to have two different images.
Any Ideas?

Comment: WHY? They all use the same driver and same pins and most are software compatible. I suggest you forget about DS1307 as most use 5V.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is because of backward compatibility with our SD image for different customers.  Ok, I got you point, probably two images will be best solution

Comment: You could try both with `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231`. The RTC both have identical registers 0-6 (which AFAIK are the only ones used). DS3231 has alarms and additional functions (not used by driver).

Comment: You mean both dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231 and dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307 and dtoverlay=merged ?

Comment: If I meant anything other than what I suggested I would have said so. Have you ACTUALLY generated a merged overlay using ovmerge ?

Comment: This is my current config: 
`dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
dtparam=i2c_vc=on
#dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307
dtoverlay=merged`